# How can I create a keyboard shortcut to open a document, not just an app?

Tags: windows-8

Every other recent version of Windows let you create a shortcut and assign it a key combination in its properties, like `Ctrl + Alt + N`. Windows 8 seems to only allow you to open apps this way, not documents. How can I regain this ability for the multiple text files and spreadsheets whose shortcuts are in my muscle memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would find [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com) very useful.